# Host Website On Virtual Machine

Tags: networking, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I know how to set up a VM, and I know how to bridge the connection so that the VM can have outside access.  However, is it possible to set the VM to a different IP address than the host machine?

Meaning, let's say I have port 90 forwarded to LAN IP 192.168.8.500 and that is the IP that I want to set to my VM, and my host machine IP is 192.168.8.12.  I think a good way to phrase it is, I would need my LAN IP of 192.168.8.12 to forward any requests from port 90 on to the VM.

Is it possible to configure a VM set-up like this?

Comment: Yes, are you using Bridged Networking already?  Does your router support static leases?

Comment: @heavyd - not sure if router supports this.  I have had a dedicated PC to simply host a website, and was wanting to move it onto a VM on a  more powerful server install, but wasn't sure if it was feasible.  Now I know.

Comment: Host and guest need to have different intranet addresses to do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's exactly what bridged networking does. It puts the virtual machine on the same subnet as the host, so other computers see them as completely separate. If you assign a certain LAN IP to the VM, that's the IP you should portforward to. The router will see it as a destination like any other. (You can't give it a `.500` address though, since that's bigger than 255.)

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can

Bridged networking is like you have a switch where your host and guest connected at the same time.

So your guest should have different IP address in a fact, or you will have IP address conflict instead.